# Return an array item that doesn't match any item in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have two identical arrays of objects.

I then add an object to one of the arrays at a random index:

`Arr1 = [{ id: "a" }, { id: "b" }, { id: "c" }]`

`Arr2 = [{ id: "a" }, { id: "d" }, { id: "b" }, { id: "c" }]`

How would I go about comparing the two arrays, extracting that new object from Arr2 and assigning that object to a constant?

This is my best effort:

```
const newPlan
if (state.plans.length !== data.allPlansJson.edges.length) {
    data.allPlansJson.edges.map(staticPlan => {
        state.plans.map(planInState => {
            planInState !== staticPlan && newPlan = staticPlan
        })
    })
}
```

Too add even more context:

I'm getting objects from the array `data.allPlansJson.edges` and spreading them in my a database collection. I'm then getting all of those objects and putting them back into an array in my redux state.

This function is to detect when there is a new object added to the `data.allPlansJson.edges` array and execute a redux action that posts this new object to my database collection.

Comment: have the objects (with same values) the same object reference?

Comment: Why don't you just assign it to whatever you want and add it after?

Comment: Is `id` property unique between all the objects? Or you could add an object with a duplicated `id` on the new array?

Comment: @Shidersz the id's are identical yes. For example the id of { id: "a" } in both arrays is exactly the same.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. The objective here is to help you with *your code*, not to write it all for you

Comment: @charlietfl I've appended my attempt to the question. I realise why this isn't working but I also can't see how to do what I want.

Comment: Multiple questions: **(1)** Are they references to the same object, or clones of the object? **(2)** Is "doesn't match" defined by solely the `id` being different? Or, will there be some time down the road where these objects have more properties? **(3)** Will the 'outlier' always be in `Arr2`? **(4)** If you have an array of `[{id: "A"}, {id: "B"}]`, why not just an array `let ids = ["A", "B"]`?

Comment: @TylerRoper they are clones. I'm comparing the objects solely on the id and the id will be exactly the same as the equivalent object. The objects will consist of much more than just the id key-value pair.

Comment: How are you cloning them? If you could share how the second array is created/populated, it would be helpful.

Comment: @TylerRoper I've added context to the question.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific scenario, in order to get just the new items you can filter out any points that are in the orignial.

```
const arrA = [{ id: "a" }, { id: "b" }, { id: "c" }];
const arrB = [{ id: "a" }, { id: "d" }, { id: "b" }, { id: "c" }];

const newItems = arrB.filter(b => !arrA.some(a => a.id === b.id));
```

`arrB.filter` loops over `arrB` calling the arrow function. To keep an item we return true in this callback. To get rid of an item we return false.

`arrA.some` loops over `arrA` calling the provided arrow function. The function will resolve true if *any* of the items return true. Since we are matching for items found in the array we add the `!` before `arrA.some` in order to find items  *not* found

You can now grab the first item from `newItems` by doing

```
const [someConst] = newItems;
```

---

Note: this is a one-way search. If there are new ones in `arrA` they will not be found

Comment: A bit nickpicky here but is there any benefit to destructuring, i.e. (`const [someConst] = newItems;`), instead of the well-known-to-every-developer-ever `newItems[0]`?

Comment: In this scenario, no real benefit. I personally prefer it as if I'm grabbing the first item in an array, I'll probably be wanting to grab the rest to via `const [first, ...rest] = someArray;`.

Answer (score 1):

You could `find` the object by checking the object with with the one at the same index.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: "a" }, { id: "b" }, { id: "c" }],
    array2 = [{ id: "a" }, { id: "d" }, { id: "b" }, { id: "c" }],
    inserted = array2.find((o, i) => o.id !== array1[i].id);

console.log(inserted);
```

Comment: @TylerRoper, please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Arr1 = [{ id: "a" }, { id: "b" }, { id: "c" }];
Arr2 = [{ id: "a" }, { id: "d" }, { id: "b" }, { id: "c" }];

function findExtra(arr1, arr2) {
  len1 = arr1.length;
  len2 = arr2.length;
  for (i = 0; i < Math.min(len1, len2); i++) {
    if (arr1[i].id !== arr2[i].id) { // Compare elements pairwise
       return len1 > len2 ? arr1[i] : arr2[i]; // Return the newly added one
    }
  }
  // The new element is the last one
  return len1 > len2 ? arr1[len1 - 1] : arr2[len2 - 1];
}

console.log(findExtra(Arr1, Arr2));
```

Is this what you are looking for?